# Fixed Point Numbers

Tags: java, fixed-point

I am stuck on a project in my intro to Java class.

We have to create a code that will convert a number to a Fixed Point Number. I've got that part okay, but where I am stuck is in the mathematics portion of our assignment. We have to add, subtract, multiple w/ (scalar (float) method, and divide with scalar (float) method.

Here is the code I have so far. If anyone could help point me in the right direction to getting a second number output and having the two numbers add, I would appreciate it.

```
public class FixedNumber {
public static final int lastSix = Integer.parseInt("111111", 2);
int value;
int value2;

public FixedNumber(int value) {
    this.value = value << 6;
}
public FixedNumber(int integral, float decimal) {
    this.value = (integral << 6) + (int)(decimal % 1 * 50);
}
public FixedNumber(float value) {
    this.value = ((int)value << 6) + (int)(value % 1 * 50);
}
public String toString() {
    return (value >> 6) + "." + ((value & lastSix) * 2);
    //return "" + ((value << 26) >>> 26);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FixedNumber number = new FixedNumber(12786783, 0.87654f); //integral, decimal
    FixedNumber number2 = new FixedNumber(3.876545f); //value
    System.out.println(number);
    System.out.println(number2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a method for each action in your `FixedNumber` class. The method would act on the current FixedNumber object (`this`) and the passed in parameter.

```
public FixedNumber add(FixedNumber toAdd) {
    // adds the two numbers and returns the result
}

public FixedNumber multiply(FixedNumber toMultiply) {
    // multiplies the two numbers and returns the result
}

// ... etc ...
```

You can take a look at the [source for BigDecimal](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/BigDecimal-source.html) to see an example.

Comment: But better to ignore the naming of BigDecimal and instead go for more sensible names. `add` implies changing the given instance, something like `plus` makes it clearer that we return a new object.

Comment: I guess that is still a little vague for my understanding. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I think that fixed point is a little awkward (shift six places? 1/50 unit?). I would start with something like this:

```
public class MyBigDecimal {
    private long scaledValue;
    private int decimalPlaces;
    public MyBigDecimal(double v, int places) {
        long factor = (long)Math.pow(10.0, places);
        scaledValue = Math.round(v * factor);
        decimalPlaces = places;
    }

    public double doubleValue() {
        double factor = Math.power(10.0, decimalPlaces);
        return scaledValue / factor;
    }
```

}

If you want to operate with that other "fixed point" that is neither decimal or binary, you certainly have a challenge.